# Insert row event in Excel VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

As a simpler way of saying "[how to handle resize of range upon insert column/row in Excel via VSTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410761/how-to-handle-resize-of-range-upon-insert-column-row-in-excel-via-vsto)":

Is there a way in excel VSTO to handle "insert row" or "insert column" event?

Comment: Seems that there is not such event, but Range objects automatically adapt to inserted rows, columns and cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event in Excel. You can pick up when a row is inserted or deleted via the [Worksheet.Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.change(VS.80).aspx) or [Application.SheetChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220992(office.11).aspx) events.

For a detailed discussion of this see the article [Deleted Rows](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/08/21/capture-deleted-rows/) by Dick Kusleika.

But if all you wanted to achieve was to ensure that your range object resizes when a row is inserted, then, as you noted, [there is is nothing that you need to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410761/how-to-handle-resize-of-range-upon-insert-column-row-in-excel-via-vsto), as the Range object would expand automatically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How about if a column is added at the end of a range, again over the Worksheet.Change? This wont be Range.Resize...

Answer (score 0):

Ranges resize automatically so you shouldn't usually have to do anything to your objects, and there isn't a RowInserted event. If you want to be notified when rows are inserted you have to use the `Worksheet.Change` instead.

The fastest way I've found to check whether a rows have been changed in this event handler is to compare `Target.Address == Target.EntireRow.Address`. These will return true when rows are inserted, deleted or moved with cut/insert. You could do the same with `Target.EntireColumn` for columns. Note that this will also return true if the insert fails (e.g. if there is a pivot table in the way and Excel aborts the insert)

For me that was exactly what I wanted and it was ok to run on failed actions.

```
private void ActiveWorksheet_Change(Excel.Range Target)
{
    if(Target.Address == Target.EntireRow.Address)
    {
        //do stuff on insert/delete/cut+insert
    }
}
```

---

If you need to get ONLY inserts, deletes, or cut/inserts of rows, or if you need to do something different when the operation fails, you can do what I tried first:

Store `Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` in a `Dictionary<string, int>` with the `Worksheet.Name` as the key. Then you compare the new `Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` to the saved count and act accordingly. Note that this will break in fun ways after sheet renames or if a new sheet gets an old sheet's name unless you find a way to trap those types of events and update/delete Dictionary entries but I haven't found a better way to ID sheets so you'll have to account for that.